# Por que não consigo inserir dados no formulário com Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Eu estou trabalhando em um projeto e ele requer um robô que entre neste site: *https://transparencia.e-publica.net/epublica-portal/#/chapeco/portal/compras/licitacaoTable*

Estou trabalhando com Selenium para automatização e raspagem e o primeiro passo requer inserir o dado ***Aguardando abertura*** na caixa **Situação** no "formulário" no topo da página para filtrar os arquivos que busco. Estou usando este código aqui:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

url = "https://transparencia.e-publica.net/epublica-portal/#/chapeco/portal/compras/licitacaoTable"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# Deixar o texto "Aguardando abertura" visível
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Situação']/../../../div[@class='filtro-espacamento col-xs-12 col-sm-8']/div/div/div/div[@class='chosen-container chosen-container-single epublica-enum form-control epublica-select-sm']/a/div/b").click()

# Achar a tag "Select" que contem a opção "Aguardando abertura"
y = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Situação']/../../../div[@class='filtro-espacamento col-xs-12 col-sm-8']/div/div/div/select")
select_object = Select(y)
time.sleep(5)

select_object.select_by_value('string:Aguardando abertura')

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Eu não o que está dando que eu não consigo manipular a tag Select do texto HTML da página pois sempre me aparece a mensagem:

> ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

e imaginei que deixando o texto visível fosse funcionar pois achei que fosse esse o problema mas continua dando o mesmo erro. Eu preciso disso para filtrar os arquivos que busco.

Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: Pelo o que parece o Select coloca o texto dentro de uma tag span, que normalmente não é interativa. A questão é como eu posso colocar o texto ou contornar essa situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você descreveu no comentário, o elemento não é interativo por meio do select.

Outra forma para selecionar o elemento desejado é a seguinte:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

url = "https://transparencia.e-publica.net/epublica-portal/#/chapeco/portal/compras/licitacaoTable"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

# Deixar o texto "Aguardando abertura" visível
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Situação']/../../../div[@class='filtro-espacamento col-xs-12 col-sm-8']/div/div/div/div[@class='chosen-container chosen-container-single epublica-enum form-control epublica-select-sm']/a/div/b").click()

# Achar a tag "Select" que contem a opção "Aguardando abertura"
y = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Situação']/../../../div[@class='filtro-espacamento col-xs-12 col-sm-8']/div/div/div/select")
select_object = Select(y)
time.sleep(1)

# Encontrar o elemento para seleção
element_for_select = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='advancedSearchModal']/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]")
time.sleep(1)

element_for_select.click()
driver.close()
```

Desse modo após abrir o menu com select o selenium vai buscar o dado que está ativo no momento.